# Vertically align Bootstrap 4 navbar collapse button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to center the collapse button, when the height of the navbar is unknown? I can do something like:

```
.navbar-toggler {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    height: 40; /*something appropriate*/
}
```

Now the button is vertically aligned. However, when I open the menu (click on it), it will center on the text as well, which is something I don't want. Play around with it here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKbJJV

I also want to make the logo float right when it's in "mobile view". Is that possible without using media queries perhaps?

Comment: not possibe this way.. you have to wrap the collapse button and brand logo in a div to get the a fx height.. As when we open the menu in case of mobile the height of nav becomes variable.

Comment: @SahilDhir Even if I wrap them in a div and do `class="d-flex align-items-center"` it won't work, as the button is positioned absolute.

Comment: can you create a pen using it?

Comment: @SahilDhir Got it to work. Posting an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by wrapping the button and brand in a div like this:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand ml-3" href="/en">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

Then I did some CSS on the button as well:

```
.navbar-toggler {
  align-self: inherit;
  position: initial;
}
```

And that's pretty much it. Solved both issues!